# Prove that $f : \mathbb R \smallsetminus \{−1\} \to\mathbb R \smallsetminus \{1\}$ given by $f(x) = \frac{x − 3}{x + 1}$ is bijective

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

I know for a function to be bijective it must be one to one and onto.
Here's what I have

Take by cases
*Case 1 (one to one)*

$$ \begin{align*}
\frac{x-3}{x+1} &= \frac{y-3}{y+1} \\[1ex]
(x-3)(y+1)&=(x+1)(y-3) \\[1ex]
xy+x-3y-3&=xy-3x+y-3
\end{align*} $$

cleaning up we get

$$4x=4y$$

so

$$x=y$$

The function is one to one.

*Case two (onto)*
$$ \begin{align*}
y&=f(x)\\[1ex]
y&= \frac{x-3}{x+1}\\[1ex]
y(x+1)&=x-3 \\[1ex]
yx+y&=x-3  \\[1ex]
yx-x&=-3-y  \\[1ex]
x(y-1)&=-3-y  \\[1ex]
x&= \frac{-3-y}{y-1}
\end{align*} $$

The function is onto.

Are we done here? Anything I should add?

Comment: No. It's correct!

Comment: I wonder why no one observed that you *had* wrong parenthesis but, hey, teach their own.

Comment: Did i type the parenthesis in wrong?oops

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, simply note that $$f(x) = 1 - \frac{4}{x+1}$$

The fraction takes on all values except $0$ hence $f$ takes on all values except $1$. It is injective clearly since $\frac{4}{a} = \frac{4}{b} \Longleftrightarrow a=b$ where neither $a$ nor $b$ are $0$.

Comment: Thats a little easier to see!thank you